# Photo slideshow with waypoints/groups

Tags: windows, image-viewer, slideshow

I'm looking for a program that can play a slideshow of images and have either waypoints or photo groups that I can quickly jump to.

Here's what I need it for:
I'm organising an event and I need to have slideshows playing during some speaches. Obviously, I can't just rely on pre-defined timings, so I want to do the following:

When the fist person starts talking, I want to start the slideshow. Then, when they're done talking, I want to press a button and switch to the next set of images for the next speech (and repeat that for a few speeches).

Any recommendations?

Comment: Can try with Simply Slideshow which is a free utility which can actually spice up your ‘View photos as Slideshow’ experience by adding some effects to it.